# Converting sympy expression to numpy expression before solving with fsolve( )

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, nonlinear-optimization, lambdify

I have a system of equations expressed by sympy:

```
def test1a(A):
    t, tt = sym.symbols('t tt')
    return sym.cos(t+tt+A)*A

def test1b(B):
    t, tt = sym.symbols('t tt')
    return sym.sin(t-tt+B)*B
```

That I want to convert to a numpy expression before evaluating the result with `fsolve()`:

```
def testprep(variables, A, B):
    
    t, tt = sym.symbols('t tt')
    
    fA = lambdify([(t, tt)], test1a(A))
    fB = lambdify([(t, tt)], test1b(B))
    
    t, tt = variables
    
    return [fA,fB]

def testsolve(A, B):
    
    print(so.fsolve(testprep, [-1, 1], args = (A, B)))
    
    return
```

When ran, I get the following result:

```
import scipy.optimize as so
import sympy as sym
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify as lambdify
import numpy as np

def main():
    A = 1
    B = 2
    testsolve(A,B)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

---

As a sanity check, I drafted the same system in terms of numpy expressions and solved it:

```
def standard(variables, A, B):
    
    t, tt = variables
    
    eq1 = np.cos(t+tt+A)*A
    eq2 = np.sin(t-tt+B)*B
    
    return [eq1, eq2]

def solvestandard(A, B):
    
    print(so.fsolve(standard, np.array([-1, 1]), args = (A,B)))
    
    return
```

With output:

```
[-0.71460184  1.28539816]
```

I'm new to `lambdify( )` and am not too familiar with the process of converting from sympy to numpy. What would I need to change in order to make the test-case work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've presented your code in a very convoluted way for an SO question. You don't need so many functions just to show what is basically 5 lines of code!

Please reduce your examples to something as simple as possible that is a single block of code that can be copy-pasted complete with all imports. Then please test it by copy-pasting and running in a fresh python process.

The way to use `lambdify` with `fsolve` is something like:

```
import sympy as sym
import scipy.optimize as so

t, tt = sym.symbols('t tt')
A, B = 1, 2
eq1 = sym.cos(t+tt+A)*A
eq2 = sym.sin(t-tt+B)*B
f = lambdify([(t, tt)], [eq1, eq2])
print(so.fsolve(f, [-1, 1]))
```

The idea is that lambdify makes an efficient function that can be computed many times (e.g. `fsolve` will call it iteratively). Then you pass that efficient function to `fsolve`.

The function that you pass to `fsolve` should not call `lambdify` itself (as your `testprep` does) because `lambdify` is a lot slower than evaluating the function:

```
In [22]: %time f = lambdify([(t, tt)], [eq1, eq2])
CPU times: user 4.74 ms, sys: 77 µs, total: 4.82 ms
Wall time: 4.96 ms

In [23]: %time f([1, 2])
CPU times: user 36 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 37 µs
Wall time: 41 µs
Out[23]: [-0.6536436208636119, 1.682941969615793]
```

Maybe your real problem is more complicated but I would use sympy's `nsolve` for something like this:

```
In [16]: nsolve([eq1, eq2], [t, tt], [-1, 1])
Out[16]: 
⎡-0.714601836602552⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎣ 1.28539816339745 ⎦

In [17]: nsolve([eq1, eq2], [t, tt], [-1, 1], prec=100)
Out[17]: 
⎡-0.714601836602551690384339154180124278950707650156223544756263851923045898428447750342991293664470733⎤
⎢                                                                                                      ⎥
⎣1.285398163397448309615660845819875721049292349843776455243736148076954101571552249657008706335529267 ⎦
```

SymPy's `nsolve` takes care of calling `lambdify` for you. It is somewhat slower than `fsolve` because it works with arbitrary precision floating point but that means it can also compute more accurate results.

Comment: `help(f)` should show the `numpy` code that was created.  Sometimes `lambdify` produces a bad result because it does a rather naive lexical translation (without a 'deep' knowledge of `numpy`).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, this is a great answer. Coding in a more pythonic way is something I struggle with, but your explanation addresses my main problems. If nsolve can accept additional arguments in the form of an array of constants it may be something I look into.

Comment: Rather than passing in additional arguments just substitute those values into `eq1` and `eq2` before calling `nsolve`.

Comment: I.e. if `A` and `B` are symbols then you can do `eq1.subs({A:5, B:4})`.